How set up Crystal report PageLayout,PageSize when we Use PrintReport() method instead of PrintToPrinterMethod
How to set up Crystal report PageLayout,PageSize when we Use PrintReport() method instead of PrintToPrinterMethod()
var opt = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.PrintReportOptions();
opt.PrinterName = printerSettings.PrinterName;
_report.ReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.PrintReport(opt);

In this example, where I need to add PageLayout, PageSize?
Please help me. I'm new for C# development
